# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when attempting to choose specific objects from a float list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Good morning everyone, I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I tried to search for this question and can't find any good answer so I'm asking one myself.

Basically,

```
    AccessoriesPrice = (0.00, 50.00, 19.99, 15.99)

    for count,(case) in enumerate((AccessoriesPrice[1])):
        print(count,"|",case,">>")
```

I'm currently programming a test app that uses lists as a way to store lists of available phones and accessories and their prices, and then outputs them in a menu, which then prompts them to choose a number, which eventually goes to use the numbers in the lists with stored input numbers in variables. Kind of like `AccessoriesPrice[1]` This code above is part of it.

For some reason, when I run the code to the terminal, it says `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`, and I kinda understand what does the error mean, but I wanted to know if there could be a way where I can grab a specific number from the list with its index number without dealing with this error. Thank you for answering this question

Comment: If you want to "grab" a specific item from the list, why do you use a loop? Loops are for iterating over multiple elements and right now you are trying to iterate over `50.00` which is not possible

Comment: The exception message is pretty specific. When you put square brackets after AccessoriesPrice, it access a specific member of the list, which is a float. A float is just one value and you can't iterate over it - it's not an "iterable". If you take off the "[1]", then the loop may work.. but.. the first expression folllowing "for" looks syntactically incorrect.

Comment: To be honest its part of the program where it lists the menu. I think I should've asked the question a bit better, lemme try to reedit this question.

Comment: Did you mean `enumerate(AccessoriesPrice, start=1)`? This will loop the list and save the `count` as the index for each element, but starting from `1` instead of `0`

Comment: Is AccessoriesPrice supposed to be a list/tuple of floats, or is it a list/tuple of tuples of floats? Maybe extend it a bit for the sake of example.

Comment: supposed to be a list/tuple of floats. I honestly think I asked the wrong question. I was trying to get the numbers with a range of index, like `AccessoriesPrice[0:1]`, so I'd get 0.0 and 50.0, but it only prints [0.0] for some reason, instead of the more preferable [0.0,50.0]

Comment: @Nour_T. this is because the `end` is exclusive. So `list[0:1]` will give you the first item, while `list[0:4]` will give you the first four items. Why don't you try to [edit] your question to be more clear, or delete this one and ask a new one. Use the [ask] section to help you. Don't forget to post a [mre]

Comment: I will, this was quite the experience as a first time using this website, but thank you for clarifying about this. I'll make sure next time I ask a question I don't mess it up again. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [1] from it.

```
AccessoriesPrice = (0.00, 50.00, 19.99, 15.99)

    for count,(case) in enumerate((AccessoriesPrice)):
        print(count,"|",case,">>")
```

Comment: I did just realize that I can't iterate just a single number of float while at the loop, I honestly asked a wrong question. Thank you for your time though!